# Android service being stopped, how to notify applications?

Tags: android, service, android-pendingintent

I have an application which works like a framework - other apps can register a PendingIntent with my app which triggers them at some point in the future. I am keeping the PendingIntents in an array list in a service and then iterating over them to trigger. To register an intent the application calls "startService()" with a PendingIntent set within the intent bundle.

At some point, my service is being closed - or more specifically my array list is being emptied (which can only happen by Android killing the service) and as such I loose my PendingIntents for the registered apps.

How can I keep my service alive, or more specifically keep my PendingItents from being lost? I don't want to go against the Android system mechanisms and create a hacky effort, I would like to know the way in which Google think this should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a service is killed, it's onDestroy() method is called. You could probably over-ride the onDestroy() method and do something like:

```
public void onDestroy(){
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("SERVICESTOPPED");
sendBroadcast(intent);
super.onDestroy();  
}
```

Have a BroadcastReceiver that listens to this intent and handle the situation as and when it happens.
Alternatively, in the onstartCommand(), if you specify the return value as START_STICKY, the OS will restart your service if it gets killed by OS. Generally this happens with long running serices

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Put your code here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

You can try [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)

Comment: I haven't - but I will try this. I was under the impression that this wouldn't guarantee the service stayed open, rather a hint to the OS that it should?

Comment: This does not guarantee the service to stay open, but rather tells the OS to create the service again when the resources are available again. One problem with START_STICKY though is that the bundle in onStartCommand is empty, this is something i am working to find a workaround because i am facing that issue right now.